# OR operator in mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb

Working of OR operator in mongodb with php

```
$query = array(
        'table' => $table,
        'user_id' => array('$ne'=> null),
        '$or' => array('movies' => array('$ne' => null), 'comics' => array('$ne' => null) )
    );

$dbcollection->find($query);
```

Here I try to return whole records where movies array or comics array is not null, But I always return empty array.
In database, movies or comics array is present in some records and some other records no movies or comics array is present.

How can I correct this query ?

Comment: @Micku: I using  version 1.0.4 or 'OR' operator needs v1.6+, is it ?

Comment: "OR" operator is included only from version 1.7.x onwards.

Comment: When you say "1.0.4", do you mean the server version or the PHP Driver version? Try logging in with the mongo shell (type `mongo`) and it will tell you which version you are it. In any case, PHP driver version 1.0.4 is *really* old. And I don't think MongoDB version 1.0.4 exists. Don't you mean 2.0.4? Also, post a sample document with your question so we can have a look at what is stored.

Comment: @Derick: Can I get Mongo version from php code itself ?

Comment: Yes: $m = new Mongo(); $d = $m->yourDb; $r = $d->command( array( "serverStatus" => 1 ) ); echo $r["version"] );

Comment: @Derick: Thanks, The mongo version is 1.4.4.

Comment: Can you post the sample document with your question?

Comment: Please upgrade! Mongo 1.4.4 is really really old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments indicate that you are using MongoDB 1.4.4. The `$or` operator did not get introduced until MongoDB 1.6 as per [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or). MongoDB 1.4.4 is also really really old. Please upgrade!

Comment: Its my local server mongo version is 1.4.4, but in production server where the mongo version is 1.6.2 is also not working the `OR` operator. Any way Thanks for help...